# Can I test android apps on a phone with no phone service

Tags: android

Can one buy a used device with no phone service and use it for testing apps?

Second question:  can wifi be used on such a phone, to connect to the internet?

Answer (score 3):

### **Yes you can!** :)

```
( You can connect to wifi too! )
```

> The following links maybe of interest
>   to you:
>
> http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/market/apps/app/bohlool.net.wifiadb/ADB-over-WIFI-Widget
>
> http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Answer (score 2):

Why not?

I recently traveled through Canada without phone service, and used my Android to connect to the hotel wifis, no problem at all. Moreover, you can install apps via file copy and a program like astro manager, or use the debug interface over USB.

You cannot test an app for telephony, obviously :-)